# Help understanding this numerical surface integration technique?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, surface-integrals, programming

I'm attempting to write a FORTRAN program that calculates the magnetic field, B, at any point outside of a bar magnet.

I'm going to use a first order euler scheme, where each side of the bar magnet is split into small cells, each with centres at (xi,yi,zi). I know I can ignore all of the sides that have any z values, and just focus on the top and bottom sides that are orientated in the x-y plane. So the method says this:

$\int f(x,y,z)dS = \Delta S \cdot  \sum f(x_{i},y_{i}, z_{i})$

where the integral is over the surface S, and the summation is over i.

Delta S, each area, is given by $\hat{n}\cdot d\vec{S}$ , so if the cell is oriented in the x-y plane it's just $\Delta x\cdot \Delta y$ .

[Here is a screenshot of the specific method instructions with a figure that demonstrates it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd3Gf.png)

The function for the magnetic field is this: $\vec{B}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\mu _{0}}{4\pi }\cdot \int\frac{(r-{r}')\cdot M(r)\cdot \hat{n}}{|(r-{r}')|^{3}}$

Where the integral is over the surface S

I'm struggling to understand this method. I've tried to construct a flow chart, but can't get very far so I figured the problem is with the mathematics. Any help to understand it would be appreciated, and also any help with the flow chart would be fantastic. [Here is my flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKaOH.png)

Thanks

Comment: Cross-post [scicomp.stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28815/help-understanding-this-numerical-surface-integration-technique)